# Add crontab job EC2 instance Operation not permitted

Tags: amazon-ec2, cron, cron-task

I'm trying to add new job to crontab using `crontab -e` with root user on linux ec2 instance. However I'm getting Operation not permitted while I'm trying to save my changes. And I got same error while I'm trying to add job using any other user.
Moreover I can find in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` root user but I cannot find another user. Also the result of `ls -l` for /var/spool/cron/crontabs is `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 112 Apr  7 03:21 root`

How can I add the new job without getting operation not permitted error?

Comment: `sudo crontab -e`...

Comment: Tried sudo and switching to root user as well and still getting operation not permitted